# Excel formula not working while trying to calculate overtime or lesser time

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I need to create a formula which will return overtime/lesser-time of employees based upon time duration.

I want to put the formula in column Q.

[image]

The requirement is such that -

- If Total Duration(column O) is 0, then OT Hours = 0.
- If Total Duration is >12 and Employment Type = Contractor, OT Hours =
  12-O6 else O6-12.
- If Total Duration is >8 and Employment Type <> Contractor, OT Hours =
  8-O6 else O6-8.

I have entered the following formula but it is not working.

```
=IF(O6<>0,((IF(AND(D6<>"Contractor",O6>8),O6-8,8-O6),IF(AND(D6="Contractor",O6>12),O6-12,12-`O6))),0)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
=IF(O6=0,0,IF(D6="Contractor",IF(O6>12,O6-12,12-O6),IF(O6>8,O6-8,8-O6)))
```

Comment: Yup. Solved. Just needed to reverse the [value_if_true] in both IF statements.